# JSON object array is not mapping correctly to Web API model?

Tags: angularjs, asp.net-web-api2

I have a `JSON object that contains an array`.  When I make a post to an api, all the fields map properly exept for the array.  Here is the JSON object:

```
productInformation: {
      productStatus: "",
      otherExplanation: "",
      partNumbersReturned: []
}
```

Here is my Web API model:

```
public string ProductStatus { get; set; }
public string OtherExplanation { get; set; }
public List<string> PartNumbersReturned { get; set; }
```

When I make the following call, which hits my Web API, I can see ProductStatus and OtherExplanation are blank, but PartNumbersReturned has no elements:

```
var insertForm = function (form) {
            return $http.post("http://localhost:59437/api/form/Post", form).then(
                function(results) {
                    alert("success");
                });
           };
```

I have tried setting the `PartNumbersReturned` property to an array `[]` and a `List<string>`, but no luck either way.

Answer (score 0):

In success callback you set data with result. 
in then, you use .data, so:

```
return $http.post("http://localhost:59437/api/form/Post", form).then(
                function(results) {
                    console.log('result data: ',results.data);
                    alert("success");
                });
```

Comment: When I inspect data, it is blank. Results status is 204 and statusText is "No Content"

Comment: If data is blank, then receiving JSON is blank. So something with backend. See how to generate JSON with array from WEB API.

Comment: Sorry, I jumped to a conclusion.  I was returning void in my API method, once I returned my object, the json object is populated.  The only part that is not returned is the array

Answer (score 0):

The solution was to do:

```
public List<object> PartNumbersReturned { get; set; }
```

instead of

```
public List<string> PartNumbersReturned { get; set; }
```